# what is / . / mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In DNA strings, symbols "A" and "T" are complements of each other, as "C" and "G". You have function with one side of the DNA (string, except for Haskell); you need to get the other complementary side. DNA strand is never empty or there is no DNA at all (again, except for Haskell).

```
function DNAStrand(dna) {
  return dna.replace(/./g, function(c) {
    return DNAStrand.pair[c]
})
}

  DNAStrand.pair = {
     A: 'T',
     T: 'A',
     C: 'G',
     G: 'C',
}
```

Comment: It's a regex delimiter : see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp for example. Here the regex is used with the replace() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `regex` pattern. It's generally used for text parsing and manipulation, which includes matching, replacing, and more. A quick google search will explain the syntax.

Comment: thank you! in regular expressions, the dot (.) is a special character used to match any one character. In written language, the period (.) is used to indicate the end of a sentence.

Comment: If it helped, could you click the green check next to the answer?